# Android: How to open a video file using MediaStore with ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, exoplayer, mediastore, android-11

I am trying to play the local video files using MediaStore API but all I see is I can access it as an OpenFileDiscriptor object or as InputStream.
But ExoPlayer doesn't have any of these methods to support.
So now how can I open this file using MediaStore API and Play it with Android 10+?

Also, does anyone knows this as well how can I create and save a video with Native Libs? such as FFmpeg using MediaStore API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to get Content Uri

```
val contentUri: Uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

Get the `Cursor`

```
...

val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(contentUri, projection,
    selection,
    selectionArgs, sortOrder)
...
```

Get the `id` of the file

```
...
val id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID))
...
val fileUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        id
                    )
```

Using this uri, create `exoplayer` `MediaSource`

```
val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
            context,
            "exoplayer-example"
        )
val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(fileUri)
```

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media?hl=fr) and [this](https://gist.github.com/Varsha-Kulkarni/78c009cf1a90a9204e5c72c5e60944ee).

Please post the second part as a separate question, I haven't used any native libs with `MediaStore` APIs. Perhaps returned `uri` can be used.

Comment: This solution won't be going to work here directly as it throws **IllegalSeekPositionException** exception and also the URI that you got is just a temp. URI. e.g: content://media/external/video/media/31014.

Comment: [IllegalSeekPositionException](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/IllegalSeekPositionException.html) is thrown when when an attempt is made to seek to a position that does not exist in the player's Timeline. Please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media?hl=fr) for MediaStore APIs. It is working perfectly fine both in Android 10 and 11.

Comment: Also check [this](https://gist.github.com/Varsha-Kulkarni/78c009cf1a90a9204e5c72c5e60944ee) for getting all the videos using `MediaStore` APIs.

Comment: Yes buddy you were right. this solution is working with ExoPlayer using Media Store API. Tested with Android 10. (y)

Comment: I got everything sorted out and now everything is working perfectly and more importantly without `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions and with the Use of [Media Store](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#kotlin) I can now play the videos with ExoPlayer and also able to work with FFmpeg as well.

Answer (score 0):

You got an Uri from MediaStore.

Then open an InputStream for it:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Then give Exoplayer your stream.

O sorry... after reread i see that i misreaded.. sorry.

But then.. which methods does Exoplayer have?

Comment: ExoPlayer doesn't have any support for the input stream. [issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1086)
ExoPlayer can accept the file URI. e.g:// storage/0/....

Answer (score 0):

You could play a video file with MediaItem. MediaItem works with MediaStore Uri. Here is a sample code from the [ExoPlayer tutorial](https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html)

```
// Build the media item.
MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri);
// Set the media item to be played.
player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
// Prepare the player.
player.prepare();
// Start the playback.
player.play();
```